# Constexpr alias of overloaded template function

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

Trying to alias make_shared on a specific class type for a specific constructor of that class. My best attempt:

```
class foo { public: foo(int x) : y(x) {} int y; };
constexpr auto newfoo = static_cast<std::shared_ptr<foo>(*)(int)>(std::make_shared<foo>);
```

Yields:

```
error: invalid static_cast from type ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to type ‘std::shared_ptr<foo> (*)(int)’
constexpr auto newfoo = static_cast<std::shared_ptr<foo>(*)(int)>(std::make_shared<foo>);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) is a *variadic function template*. You are only specifying `<foo>` as a template parameter, but you would also need an `int` somewhere in there. Regardless, your approach is bound to fail as it's reliant on how `make_shared`'s template arguments were laid out and because it's generally cumbersome to work with overload sets in C++.

What I suggest is to create a wrapper function instead:

```
constexpr auto newfoo(int x)
{
    return std::make_shared<foo>(x);
}
```

In my opinion it is easier to write, read, and understand. If you *really* need SFINAE-friendliness and `noexcept`, you can [repeat the body three times](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3T4lePH-yA):

```
constexpr auto newfoo(int x) 
    ->          decltype(std::make_shared<foo>(x))
       noexcept(noexcept(std::make_shared<foo>(x)))
      {           return std::make_shared<foo>(x); }
```

A macro can be used to make the above declaration less painful.

---

If you really want a function pointer, this seems to work:

```
auto newfoo = 
    static_cast<std::shared_ptr<foo>(*)(const int&)>(
        &std::make_shared<foo, const int&>);
```

Look at `make_shared`'s declaration:

```
template< class T, class... Args >
shared_ptr<T> make_shared( Args&&... args );
```

You need to supply `T=foo` and something for `Args...`. Since `Args...` is a forwarding reference pack, it will always either deduce to *lvalue references* or *rvalue references*. This is why `<foo, const int&>` is a valid set of template parameters and `<foo, int>` is not.

As [Zefick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2865757/zefick) pointed out in the comments, all of this can be simplified to:

```
constexpr auto newfoo = &std::make_shared<foo, const int&>;
```

The cast is not really needed here.

Comment: +1, but you should probably use `const int&` instead of `int&&` in your "if you really want to" example.  As is, `const int i = 42; auto f = newfoo(i);` won't work.

Comment: `constexpr auto newfoo = std::make_shared<foo, int>` just works. Why we need the cast?